# JPA - Retrieve all Entity Classes

Tags: java, jpa, reflection, eclipselink

I need to have a List of clasess that are Persistence Entities, I need have Entity Information, using Reflection API of JPA

I have the EntityManager, But I do not know if that is the way.

I want to do a generic logging for my Entities using a EntityListener. That works well, but I do not have the way to register the listener to all my entities.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the JPA2 MetaModel? It has assorted methods to see the entities (or managed types).

```
 Set<javax.persistence.metamodel.EntityType<?>> entityTypes = entityManagerFactory.getMetamodel().getEntities();
    for (javax.persistence.metamodel.EntityType entityType : entityTypes){
        logger.info(entityType.getName());
        logger.info(entityType.getJavaType().getCanonicalName());
        logger.info("******************************");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Configuration#getClassMappings()](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/cfg/Configuration.html#getClassMappings())

> Returns: Iterator of the entity mappings currently contained in the configuration.

Comment: Thanks Predrag, Configuration is a Hibernate class, right?, In my case this not works because I am using Eclipse Link and I want to do a JPA solution.

Comment: You tagged your question with Hibernate tag, that's why I posted this. I'll edit my answer if I find a JPA way to do this.

Comment: sorry!! sorry!, It is my mistake